# Is there a method to linking a cells output based on cell being a certain date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just wanted to know if there was a method of updating a cell based on a date that was selected using the date criteria via data validation.

Ideally, it would be used to log comments inputted into a cell. The user, upon changing the date cell, would be able to see the comment made on that specific date.

I look forward to hearing any ideas.

Cheers

Comment: Could you add more details on what you have tested so far or if you are getting any error?. Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: my apologies;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dGrWftn2OyYlz9LlVsc-FB0ZtHt9KEKu-nZhI_C1BxU/edit?usp=sharing, here is the link to the specific spreadsheet.

So, ideally, the cells from j2:j4 would contain comments, the comments would be linked to the cells h2:h4. I would want specific comments to be linked to the specific dates and be changed if the user selects a new date from the cells h2:h4. I hope this makes things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Checking Date Column to set status to weekold

```
function weekold() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Name');
  const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h,i) => idx[h]=i);
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-7).valueOf()
  let vo = vs.map(r => {
    if(new Date(r[idx['Date']]).valufOf() <= dtv ) {
      r[idx['Status']] = "Week Old"
    }
    return [r[idx['Status']]];
  });
  sh.getRange(2,idx['Status']) + 1,vo.length,vo[0].length).setValues(vo);
}
```